# Apply % autocut to image

Tags: python, arrays, image, histogram, imshow

I have an image and would like to apply a 99.5% autocut to it.
I would achieve this by taking all the pixel values that makes up an image, and ranking them like a histogram. I would then take the pixels that are above 99.5% of the other pixels - and only show these chosen ones.
I have attempted this with some code, but have been unsuccessful.

```
pix_cut = np.array(sorted(img.flatten()))[int(0.995*len(img))] #sort the pixel values from the image (img) in ascending order, find the pixel value that is the 99.5% pixel
img[img < pix_cut] = 0 #any pixels below this threshold set to 0

plt.imshow(img, vmin=0, cmap='gray_r')#show image
```

Comment: Do you mean you just want to show the brightest 0.5% of the pixels and make the others black? If so, you need a 99.5% threshold. If not, you need a better explanation ;-)

Comment: Yes! How do I achieve this?